# DOM object CSS changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a application in which the UI is developed in Jquery. There are loads of templates and widgets which the js class files inherit and for displaying the screen modules.

JS class module "A" inherits template B. It uses the CSS class "ContentWrapper" to display the contents of the JS module. Now, the default text style of ContentWrapper (in template B) is right aligned. But for the js module "A" the style should be left aligned. I've accessed the DOM object in the js module "A" to change the text align to left.

```
$('.contentWrapper').css("text-align", "left");
```

But my colleague had a different approach to add a new class in the CSS file.

```
.A {
  .ContentWrapper{
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

Can someone please let me know which one would be the cheapest approach for this?

Answer (score 2):

It is best practice to separate style from interaction, that is, CSS from JavaScript, and so your colleague's approach is a better practice. With regard to "cheapness", performance will not be noticeable in either direction, but the cost of maintenance is higher for explicit jQuery changes in style.

Comment: Matt, Many thanks for the quick response. I agree with the concept seperating the style from interaction. I was bit reluctant to duplicate the values in CSS. .A {
  .ContentWrapper{
    text-align: left;
  }
} is a duplicate of the template B CSS property. Is it ok to follow this?

Comment: @Subash Assuming that the `.A` refers to a class applied to some parent element by the JS module, the duplicate value will serve to counteract the default in the case that the specific module has run.